# Using the contains function in xpath 1.0 to select numbers

Tags: regex, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and I need to scrape something like this: any number, followed by a dash, followed by any number, then a whitespace, then two letters (e.g. 1-3 mm). It seems xpath 1.0 does not allow the use of regex. Searching around, I've found some workarounds like using starts-with() and ends-with() but from what I've seen they only use it with letters. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy uses `lxml` internally, and [`lxml`'s XPath has support for regular expressions via EXSLT](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath) when you add the corresponding namespaces.

Scrapy does that by default so [you can use `re:test()` within XPath expressions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions) as a boolean for predicates.

```
boolean re:test(string, string, string?)
```

> The re:test function returns true if the string given as the first argument matches the regular expression given as the second argument.

See this example Python2 session:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> t = u"""<!DOCTYPE html>
... <html lang="en">
... <body>
... <p>ab-34mm</p>
... <p>102-d mm</p>
... <p>15-22 µm</p>
... <p>1-3 nm</p>
... </body>
... </html>"""
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=t)
>>> selector.xpath(r'//p/text()[re:test(., "\d+-\d+\s\w{2}")]').extract()
[u'15-22 \xb5m', u'1-3 nm']
>>>
```

---

Edit: note on using EXSLT `re:match`

Using [EXSLT `re:match`](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html) is a bit trickier, or at least less natural than `re:test`. `re:match` is similar to Python's `re.match`, which returns `MatchObject`

The signature is different from `re:test`:

```
object regexp:match(string, string, string?)
```

> The regexp:match function returns a node set of match elements

So `re:match` will return `<match>` elements. To capture the string from these `<match>` elements, you need to use the function as the "outer" function, not inside predicates.

The following example chains XPath expressions,

1. selecting `<p>` paragraphs
2. then matching each paragraph string-value (normalized) with a regular expression containing parenthesized groups
3. finally extracting the result of these `re:match` calls

Python2 shell:

```
>>> for p in selector.xpath('//p'):
...     print(p.xpath(ur're:match(normalize-space(.), "(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\w{2})")').extract())
... 
[]
[]
[u'<match>15-22 \xb5m</match>', u'<match>15</match>', u'<match>22</match>', u'<match>\xb5m</match>']
[u'<match>1-3 nm</match>', u'<match>1</match>', u'<match>3</match>', u'<match>nm</match>']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with xpath 1.0 you can use the translate function.

`translate(@test , '1234567890', '..........')` will replace any number (digit) with a dot.

If your numbers are always one digit you may try something like:

```
 [translate(@test , '1234567890', '..........') = '.-. mm']
```

if the numbers could be longer than on digit you may try to replace numbers with nothing and test for `- mm`

```
[translate(@test , '1234567890', '') = '- mm']
```

But this can have some **false trues**. To avoid them you will need to check with substring-before -after length if there was at least one digit

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused. Why would I replace the numbers with dots when what I need are the numbers themselves?

Comment: I thought you need to select nodes which contains numbers in a special format. If this is wrong forget translation. The goal is to extract the numbers? From a already selected node?

Comment: I think paul trmbrth's answer is exactly what I need. Thanks anyway! :)